# Iterating through ajax response object to create table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

My ajax code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#displayButton").click(function(){

var format = $("#format").val();

$.ajax({

url: 'getEmployees',
type: 'GET', 
data: {format: format},
success: function(data) {       

$('#place').text(data);

}

});

});
```

This code invokes my servlet, gets the parameter for the format and sends the data to the following section of my html:

```
<span id="place"></span>
```

When the button is pressed on my html page, the result are generated in json, xml or plain text. I am trying to format this so that they are created in a table and without all the tags etc.

I have found the following on JFiddle:

```
var jsonData = '[{"rank":"9","content":"Alon","UID":"5"},    {"rank":"6","content":"Tala","UID":"6"}]';

$.ajax({
url: '/echo/json/',
type: 'POST',
data: {
    json: jsonData
},
success: function (response) {
    var trHTML = '';
    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
        trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.rank + '</td><td>' + item.content + '</td><td>' + item.UID + '</td></tr>';
    });
    $('#records_table').append(trHTML);
}
});
```

Then in the html:

```
<table id="records_table" border='1'>
<tr>
    <th>Rank</th>
    <th>Content</th>
    <th>UID</th>
</tr>
```

But I don't think this is suitable as I am accessing my data from a servlet and don't think I can access the raw data directly in ajax.

If you know how to iterate through a list generated from the servlet in the above code, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Important thing to learn if you are a Java newbie - Java is not Javascript. This is a question about Javascript.

Comment: I am fully aware that this is a javascript/jquery issue. Other than in my username, which is not of any relevance to this question, I have not referenced 'java'. But thank you for your input.

Comment: You had tagged the question "Java" (see [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36024217/revisions)).

Comment: A simple error on the autofill. Java is simply the first four letters of the tag I meant to select. That being Javascript. Thank you for your valuable input.

Comment: If your servlet returns a json-serialized array, then your `response` will be an array in Javascript. Just make sure the content type of the servlet's response is `application/json`. See *dataType* in http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/